# Compute triple integral by changing variables

Tags: integration

I am stuck at this question and I don't know what $u$, $v$ and $w$ should I let in order to find the new boundaries of the triple integral. I tried to let $u=x^2+y^2$ and $v=(x^2+y^2)^3$, but I don't know what to do with $w$. Can someone kindly help?

Compute 
$$\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{(x^2+y^2)^3}^5\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dz\,dy\,dx.$$

I have calculated it on an online calculator and the answer is $4.88692.$
[From Wolfram Alpha calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYnOW.png)

Comment: I would try using polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, we follow JG123's suggestion, and let $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta).$ Then the integral transforms to
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{(x^2+y^2)^3}^5\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dz\,dy\,dx
&=\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\int_{(x^2+y^2)^3}^5dz\,dy\,dx\\
&=\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\left(5-(x^2+y^2)^3\right)dy\,dx\\
&=\int_0^\pi\int_0^1 r(5-r^6)\,r\,dr\,d\theta\\
&=\int_0^\pi\int_0^1 (5r^2-r^8)\,dr\,d\theta\\
&=\pi\left(\frac{5r^3}{3}-\frac{r^9}{9}\right)\bigg|_0^1\\
&=\pi\left(\frac{5}{3}-\frac{1}{9}\right)\\
&=\frac{14\pi}{9}\\
&\approx 4.887,
\end{align*}
as you got with W|A.